# Vuejs b-form-input - Unable to type when using v-model

Tags: vue.js

I'm using a `b-form-input` with `b-form-datalist`. The input text boxes will be added dynamically (one per row).

To start off, it lists a few entries. Once a value is chosen, the chosen value will be added to a list using `v-model`.

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(chosen, index) in chosenValues" :key="chosen.value + '-' + index">
      <b-col cols="4">
          <b-form-input
               list="dropdown"
               v-model="chosen.value"
           ></b-form-input>
           <b-form-datalist id="dropdown" :options="elements"></b-form-datalist>
      </b-col>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    elements: ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'avocado'],
    chosenValues: [{value: ''}] //will be added dynamically when a new text box is added
  }
})
```

The problem with this code is that I'm not able to type into the text box i.e., the focus goes away after typing a character - [Fiddle-1](https://jsfiddle.net/5kabjz63)

If I remove the `v-model` property or change it into `v-bind`, it works fine - [Fiddle-2](https://jsfiddle.net/u3p78rze/)

Answer (score 1):

I think there's some conflict using the `value` property.

I tried to replace `value` with `val` and everything works fine.

Here's the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94fv1tk3/)

Comment: Yes. You are right. Wow.. Is this a bug or did I do something that I shouldn't have (by missing something that is documented)?

Comment: Could be a bug. However, I usually avoid using standard javascript keyword for property or variable names.

Comment: Sorry for unaccepting. If I change the `:key` too to `val`, it stops working again. So, I think the issue is in the `key` attribute's value and not the property name

Comment: When we type, the v-model property changes, which affects the key. I think that is the problem.

Comment: Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tfzvL651/). I have made key value independent of the chosen value

Comment: Yes, right, I forgot to edit the key attribute. No problem for unaccepting.

Comment: Thanks for your time. You helped me figure out the mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @fabruex's answer which led to the complete answer.

The issue was in `:key="chosen.value + '-' + index"`. When typing into the input text, it binds the inputed value to the *v-model's* property. This affects the `key`'s value/bindings. This should be the reason for the problematic behavior.

Changing the key to `:key="'element-' + index"` fixes the issue.

I welcome better explanations for this :)

Comment: this happens because changing the key of a component is like remounting it. That's why the focus disappears

Comment: @fabruex Interesting that it works when using v-bind. Is it because it is one-way binding?

Comment: v-bind:key? or v-bind:value? If the second case, yes.